# where to keep images in codename one application

Tags: codenameone

I have created a single page in codename one (manual template). I can see images in codename one app emulator but when I install it on my Android phone it gives `java.lang.exception` on images code. Here is my code :

```
Form firstPage = new Form();
        try 
        {
            firstPage.getStyle().setBgImage(Image.createImage("src/com/acism/images/low_poly_background.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        
        firstPage.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        
        Label logoLabel = null;
        try {
            logoLabel = new Label(Image.createImage("src/com/acism/images/logo.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        logoLabel.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        firstPage.addComponent(c, logoLabel);
        
        Label name = new Label("Communication Is Important!");
        name.getUnselectedStyle().setFgColor(0xFFFFFF);
        name.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        firstPage.addComponent(c, name);
        
        Button btn = new Button("Get Started");
        btn.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0x3083FF, true);
        btn.getUnselectedStyle().setFgColor(0xFFFFFF);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridx = 0;
        btn.addActionListener(startedListener);
        firstPage.addComponent(c, btn);
        
        firstPage.show();
```

Note :
Images are stored on different package.

Answer (score 0):

Images can only be placed in the root of the src directory so if logo.png was there then something like:

```
Image.createImage("/logo.png")
```

Would work. However, **you shouldn't do that!**

Instead you should place the images inside the res file as [multi-images](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---fetch-an-image-from-the-resource-file---add-a-multiimage.html) which means they will adapt dynamically to the DPI of the device.

Comment: Great, Thanks Almog. You are the man. And i have a more question, i am working in Manual project, so please tell me, and i don't see any res folder in my project directory, while creating project in Manual mode.

Comment: You don't need the res folder. Just the theme.res in the src directory.